# Mail client transfer protocol without smtp

Tags: python, tcpclient

After this:

```
ssl_clientSocket.login(username, password)
```

I'm getting this error while trying to authenticate to send an email using Python.

Error:

`AttributeError: 'SSLSocket' object has no attribute 'login'`

Comment: You're going to need to add a little more to your question. Your error is happening for exactly the reason you stated - SSLSockets don't have a login method, as per the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html. What are you hoping this will do?

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with “mail client transfer protocol” and SMTP?